# I am getting raised TASKING_ERROR in Ada

Tags: exception, task, ada

I am a new to Ada, I just got an assignment to do in Ada task program and when I am trying to run a program in Ada and I am getting "raised TASKING_ERROR" while I am running in an online compiler here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_ada_online.php.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure ConTasks is

    task type SimpleTask (Message: Character; HowMany:Positive) is
        entry Start_Running;
    end SimpleTask;

    task body SimpleTask is
    begin
        for i in 1 .. HowMany loop
            delay 0.1;
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello from task "&Message);
        end loop;
    end SimpleTask;

    task_a : SimpleTask('A', 5);
    task_b : SimpleTask('B', 7);
    task_c : SimpleTask('C', 4);


    begin
        task_a.Start_Running;
        task_b.Start_Running;
        task_c.Start_Running;
    end ConTasks;
```

But when I am running the same program in  MinGW I am getting below error

```
C:\MinGW\bin>gcc -c Ada\ConTasks.ada
gcc: warning: Ada\ConTasks.ada: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

In the online compiler, I an getting the right output but in the end, it's showing below error.

```
Hello from task B
Hello from task A
.
.
Hello from task B
raised TASKING_ERROR
```

Comment: You declare an entry for the task type yet your task body never accepts the entry. Try removing the task entry from the task declaration. Instead use "task type SimpleTask(Message : Character; HowMany : Positive);".

Comment: Can we do something else, without removing the task entry? because now it's giving me this error "hello.adb:24:13: procedure or entry name expected
hello.adb:25:17: procedure or entry name expected
hello.adb:26:17: procedure or entry name expected"

Comment: You can accept the task entry before executing the loop. That means your ConTasks task must call each task entry so that each task can proceed past the accept call.

Comment: I see you call the task entries. The ConTasks task is suspended waiting for the tasks to accept their entries, and the tasks terminate before ConTasks is allowed to exit the entry queues. Simply accept the entries in the task type.

Comment: The StartRunning entry is not needed. The tasks will run automatically after they are created. That is why you can eliminate the entry in the task declaration.

Comment: But it's not working on MinGw

    C:\MinGW\bin>gcc -c Ada\ConTasks.ada
    gcc: warning: Ada\ConTasks.ada: linker input file unused because linking not done

Comment: The answer below works correctly. Try renaming your file ConTasks.adb. The GNAT compiler uses the .adb file extension for Ada body files and the .ads file extension for Ada specification files.

Comment: Regarding the `C:\MinGW\bin>gcc -c Ada\ConTasks.ada` error: the program is not even compiled! You need to rename to .adb as suggested, go into the Ada directory, `gnatmake contasks.adb` (will compile, bind and link) and run contasks.exe

Comment: GNAT expects Ada file names to be in lower case. On Windows & macOS it doesn’t make any difference, but on Linux it really does.

Answer (score 3):

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure ConTasks is

    task type SimpleTask (Message: Character; HowMany:Positive);
    task body SimpleTask is
    begin
        for i in 1 .. HowMany loop
            delay 0.1;
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello from task "&Message);
        end loop;
    end SimpleTask;

    task_a : SimpleTask('A', 5);
    task_b : SimpleTask('B', 7);
    task_c : SimpleTask('C', 4);


begin
    null;
end ConTasks;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rudra Lad's answer is almost right, the problem with it is that by enclosing the loop with the `accept` the entire thing is done inside the rendezvous, meaning the `Task` and the calling-task are both involved, so you're not taking advantage of any parallelism/concurrency.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure ConTasks is

    task type SimpleTask (Message: Character; HowMany:Positive) is
        entry Start_Running;
    end SimpleTask;

    task body SimpleTask is
    begin
        accept Start_Running do
          null;
        end Start_Running;
            for i in 1 .. HowMany loop
                delay 0.1;
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello from task "&Message);
            end loop;
    end SimpleTask;

    task_a : SimpleTask('A', 5);
    task_b : SimpleTask('B', 7);
    task_c : SimpleTask('C', 4);


begin
    task_a.Start_Running;
    task_b.Start_Running;
    task_c.Start_Running;
end ConTasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to Jim's answer, you can use the entry, if you want control over when individual task should start.

This will give you more control over your task. Since, the tasks without any entries start executing as soon as you execute the binary.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure ConTasks is

    task type SimpleTask (Message: Character; HowMany:Positive) is
        entry Start_Running;
    end SimpleTask;

    task body SimpleTask is
    begin
        accept Start_Running do
            for i in 1 .. HowMany loop
                delay 0.1;
                Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello from task "&Message);
            end loop;
        end Start_Running;
    end SimpleTask;

    task_a : SimpleTask('A', 5);
    task_b : SimpleTask('B', 7);
    task_c : SimpleTask('C', 4);


begin
    task_a.Start_Running;
    delay 2.0;
    task_b.Start_Running;
    delay 2.0;
    task_c.Start_Running;
end ConTasks;
```